# redirect non-www to www except home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I do a redirect of all non www to www version of a domain except the homepage, I have a domain at for example example.com and I want to redirect every page on that domain to www.example.com but exclude homepage from redirecting. I want to keep example.com but redirect every other page to www version of the website, I have looked everywhere here but cannot find anything.

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change you regex from  `(.*)` to  `(.+)` to avoid matching the root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: what i want is redirect example.com/* to www.example.com/* but exclude homepage(example.com)

Comment: Ok, so what exactly happens when you go to **example.com/** ? where does the request redirect to with my code?